# Usar Ionic 2 para aplicativos Windows Phone/Windows Universal?

Tags: ionic, windows-phone, ionic2

É uma dúvida recente que tenho, pretendo iniciar o desenvolvimento com o `Ionic`, porém como minha plataforma principal é o *Windows Phone*, quero saber se o *framework* dá suporte para compilação para a plataforma, e qual a maneira de adicionar essa plataforma em um projeto e compilar para a mesma, andei pesquisando mas não achei nada parecido.

E se for possível compilar para plataforma da *Microsoft*, quais requisitos para que isso possa ser feito, é possível realizar tal ação em um Linux? E como é feita tal ação?

Erro ao tentar adicionar a plataforma Windows ao projeto:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma maneira simples para desenvolver aplicativos com ionic e ionic2.

P.S: o Cordova precisa estar instalado, para instalar no Linux:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cordova-cli
npm install -g cordova
sudo apt-get install cmake debhelper libx11-dev libicu-dev pkg-config qtbase5-dev qtchooser qtdeclarative5-dev qtfeedback5-dev qtlocation5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev qtpim5-dev qtsensors5-dev qtsystems5-dev
```

1) Após a criação do projeto, entre na pasta e digite:

```
ionic platform list
```

Ele vai te listar as plataformas instaladas e as disponíveis.
2) Adicione as plataformas

```
ionic platform add ios
ionic platform add android
ionic platform add windows
```

3) Atualize o config.xml do seu projeto
As configurações do IOS e android já são feitas após o comando add, para windows insira as linhas:

```
<platform name="winphone" />
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
<preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" />
<preference name="Windows.Universal-MinVersion" value="10.0.10069.0" />
<preference name="Windows.Universal-MaxVersionTested" value="10.0.10166.0" />
```

4) Desenvolva o seu aplicativo de acordo com o seu Sistema Operacional
Você disse que usa Linux, então provavelmente está desenvolvendo para android.

5) Crie uma conta no https://build.phonegap.com . Este serviço vai fazer o build automático para você nas plataformas adicionadas ao seu projeto.

6) Faça o upload do seu projeto (zip) no build.phonegap.com ou indique o endereço do seu repositório no github

7) Mande fazer os builds do seu app

8) Você vai receber o link para baixar o aplicativo direto no seu celular ou então você usa para baixar o arquivo construido para a store

9) Siga os passos da store em questão para submeter o aplicativo

10) Fim =)

Comment: Só agora tive tempo para retomar aos estudos e aplicar sua resposta. Não consegui adicionar a plataforma Windows ao projeto, o erro está na pergunta. Já ao adicionar android o erro não se repete, mas meu objetivo é adicionar a plataforma windows

Comment: Consegui resolver instalando o Cordova duas vezes, uma por apt-get e outra por npm.. Vou completar sua resposta.